# Adding notes in the code of the Notepad3 tutorial

Tags: android

I have a question about Sql database in android.Now I"ve done the all Notepad tutorials from the Android Dev website and I wanted to go a little further by adding something new.I want to find a way to add notes in the program's code "manually" so that when the Notepad application is open in the android emulator the notes are already there.And the user can have the chance to add new notes or edit/delete the already existed ones which I"ve placed "manually" in the code.I'm sory for any potential ambiguity and any help will be great.I"ve attached the 3 classes below.Thank you.

Notepad3 Class:

```
package com.android.demo.notepad3;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;


public class Notepadv3 extends ListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes_list);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    }

    private void fillData() {
        Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case INSERT_ID:
                createNote();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                fillData();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createNote() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
        i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();
    }
}
```

NoteEdit class:

```
package com.android.demo.notepad3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NoteEdit extends Activity {

    private EditText mTitleText;
    private EditText mBodyText;
    private Long mRowId;
    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();

        setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);
        setTitle(R.string.edit_note);

        mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);

        Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

        mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
            (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if (mRowId == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                    : null;
        }

        populateFields();

        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }

    private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(note);
            mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            mBodyText.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        populateFields();
    }

    private void saveState() {
        String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
        String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();

        if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, body);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title, body);
        }
    }

}
```

NotesDbAdapter class:

```
package com.android.demo.notepad3;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Simple notes database access helper class. Defines the basic CRUD operations
 * for the notepad example, and gives the ability to list all notes as well as
 * retrieve or modify a specific note.
 * 
 * This has been improved from the first version of this tutorial through the
 * addition of better error handling and also using returning a Cursor instead
 * of using a collection of inner classes (which is less scalable and not
 * recommended).
 */
public class NotesDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "title text not null, body text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public NotesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public NotesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    /**
     * Create a new note using the title and body provided. If the note is
     * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
     * a -1 to indicate failure.
     * 
     * @param title the title of the note
     * @param body the body of the note
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createNote(String title, String body) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the note with the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all notes
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
     * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title and body
     * values passed in
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to update
     * @param title value to set note title to
     * @param body value to set note body to
     * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title, String body) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_BODY, body);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add a method to your `NotesDbAdapter.DatabaseHelper` class:

```
private void insertNotes(SQliteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("insert into notes values(1,'note title', 'note body');");
}
```

You can then call this method from either onCreate or onUpgrade.

If you think you'll want to insert a bunch of notes, you can even just define a String array containing the sql statements and then just iterate over that array in insertNotes:

```
private static final String[] DEFAULT_INSERTS = new String[] {
    "insert into notes values(1,'note title', 'note body');","insert into notes values(2,'note title2', 'note body2');"};

private void insertNotes(SQliteDatabase db){
    for(int i =0; i < DEFAULT_INSERTS.length; i++){
        db.execSQL(DEFAULT_INSERTS[i]);
}
    }
```

Then your onCreate method can look like this:

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            insertNotes(db);
        }
```

Comment: I've tried calling the method from both onCreate and onUprade but the note isn't added.

Comment: Are you sure either of those methods were being called by the system? onCreate is only called when no database file exists (i.e on first installation of your app) and onUpgrade is only called if you increment the DATABASE_VERSION value.

Comment: What changes should I make then with onCreate()?I've tried to eliminate the "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes" part from onUpgrade and still nothing

Comment: I updated my answer with the body of onCreate. Again, to ensure it's called, increment your DATABASE_VERSION value.

Comment: Thanks Chris but an argument has to be added in the "insertNotes()"...I think is should be like this insertNotes(db).The problem is that I"ve done this and unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: Wait It is done...I didn't see the part where to increment the DATABASE_VERSION.thank you Chris

Comment: One question,If I used the second approach to add more notes I"m going to have to change the DATABASE_VERSION every time?If so is there any way to do it besides changing the value when it define as a private static variable in the class?

Comment: You could put a call in the open method in your NotesDbAdapter (that'll get called whenever you open the db, though so you'd have to put logic in there to ensure you don't put more stuff in the db than you want).